# Data connection with SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I am new to foundry and I am trying to set up a data connection to a SharePoint list. I know SharePoint supports REST APIs but that is about the extent of what I know. The Foundry Data connection documentation wasn't as helpful as I had hoped.
How would I go about this? Thank you!

I think something along the lines of this:

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

I want to pull all the items from the list into a dataset and then as a new item is added have foundry grab it and put it in the dataset. I hope this is the clarification you were looking for.

Comment: Could you expand your question with some examples of the api's you want to hit and the data you want to extract?

Comment: I think something along the lines of this:
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"



and I just wan to pull all the items from the list and then as a new item is added have foundry grab it and put it in the dataset. 

I hope this is the clarification you were looking for. I am new to working with foundry. I am used to mostly working on the analytical side of data and not the technical side of linking it. Thank you!

Comment: I edited your question with the contents of your comment to better complete it. Let me take a look and I'll get back to you, there is a magritte rest source that you can use to do this. Until we drop an answer here perhaps you can take a look at the docs on data connection